# View removed VBA code after repair of Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error when opening excel: We found a problem with some content in XXX. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can? if you trust he source of this workbook, click Yes."
clicking Yes, "fixes" the issue but deletes a lot of VBA code, two weeks worth.
Whatever the issue it was introduced yesterday, I do not want to redo two weeks worth of coding. Is there anyway I can view what was removed, or open the VBA in notepad++ or something without opening the excel?

Comment: [This might help](https://superuser.com/questions/657217/recovering-vba-modules-from-corrupt-excel-workbook)

Answer (score 0):

I opened another excel workbook and tried all the different options for the argument XlCorruptLoad in the Workbooks.Open to open the corrupt workbook. I noticed that there were two non existing sheets created in the project explroer of the corrupt workbook that had the code in there. I am not sure if it did that s a result of what I did or it was there all along and I did not notice it
Note that the reason I had a corrupted data is because the code was extracting a list and putting it in a cell validation formula..i guess I overloaded it.